# Add a GeoJSON feature collection of linestrings to OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I have a GeoJSON object of line string coordinates, `geobj`

I am attempting to display them on my OL map object.

```
  var layer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geobj)
    }),
    style: new ol.style.Style({
      stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
        color: "black",
        width: 10
      }),
    })
  });

  layer.setZIndex(110);
  map_obj.addLayer(layer);
```

But nothing appears.

I have double checked the coordinates are correct, by plotting them individually on the map.

EDIT: Ran some tests, it's clear the coordiantes are fine. The issue is to do with how I generate the geojson object, I've done this using a loop - something is not quite right with the final product.

```
var geojsonObject = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'crs': {
      'type': 'name',
      'properties': {
        'name': "EPSG:27700",
      },
    },
    'features': []
  };

  $.getJSON(fn, function( data ) {

    data.features.forEach(calculateTraj);

    function calculateTraj(item){

      const MvtSpeed = item.properties.MvtSpeed;
      const MvtDirec = item.properties.MvtSpeed;

      const startLon = item.properties.LonTrajCellCG[0];
      const startLat = item.properties.LatTrajCellCG[0];

      const kmToLon = 1/(111.32 * Math.cos(startLat * (180/Math.PI)));
      let kmToLat   = 1/110.57;

      const distKMin15m = (MvtSpeed * 60 * 60)/1000;
      const alpha = (MvtDirec * (180/Math.PI));

      const deltaLon = (distKMin15m * Math.cos(alpha) * kmToLon);
      const deltaLat = (distKMin15m * Math.cos(alpha) * kmToLat);

      const endLon = parseFloat((startLon + deltaLon).toFixed(4));
      const endLat = parseFloat((startLat + deltaLat).toFixed(4));

      var t1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([(startLon), (startLat)], ukngProj)
      var t2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([(endLon), (endLat)], ukngProj)
      geojsonObject.features.push(
        {
          'type': 'Feature',
          'geometry': {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [t1], 
              [t2] ],
          },
        });
    }
  });
  return geojsonObject;
}
```

Comment: Most likely your features are very close to LonLat [0,0] if the geojson is in LonLat.  If it is try `(new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geobj, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:4326', featureProjection: map_obj.getView().getProjection()})`

Comment: That gives an error: `Uncaught TypeError: t.addEventListener is not a function`. As I say, I dont think its the coordinates, as I have plotted them manually and they appear.

Comment: @Mike Is there a way I could look at the output from `source: new ol.source.Vector({
      features: (new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geobj) })` ?

Comment: You can retrieve features with `layer.getSource().getFeatures()` call.

Comment: @TomazicM thanks - I'll see what the output there is, could be a clue.

Comment: @TomazicM this returns a blank array, could that be the issue?

Comment: Instead of posting a picture, please post your GeoJSON with a few features. But it definitely is not compliant to standard GeoJSON, which should contain unprojected coordinates. If your GeoJSON is in `EPSG:3857`, your `features` option should be: `new ol.format.GeoJSON()).readFeatures(geobj, {dataProjection: 'EPSG:3857'})`

Comment: @TomazicM - added the code that generates the geojson object to the question. After testing some output, it seems the way I am adding the features is causing an issue with the final object. If I call 'var features = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(geobj)' the variable is blank. If I call  that with a non-loop defined geojson, I get an array populated with the coordinates.

Comment: Please add a short example of generated GeoJSON. And one more question: is `geobj` generated/read async? If this is the case, data might not be available at the time of layer creation.

Comment: Ah, maybe that's it. I can't really answer that - I need to read up on async/sync, the function is called when a button is clicked. After the function does the calculations, it returns to another function which defines and displays the vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TomazicM suggested, this turned out to be a async/sync JS issue. The geojson object returns after my code attempts to display the coordinates. To get round this, I loaded the geoJSON synchronously. I know this is probably not advised, but I couldn't work out how else to do it!

Here is my adapted code:

```
// function to load gjson synchronously
function loadFileAjaxSync(fn, mimeType) {
  var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.open("GET",fn,false);
  if (mimeType != null) {
    if (xmlhttp.overrideMimeType) {
      xmlhttp.overrideMimeType(mimeType);
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.send();
  if (xmlhttp.status==200 && xmlhttp.readyState == 4 )
  {
    return xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  else {
    // TODO Throw exception
    return null;
  }
}

function calcTraj1HRSat(data){

  var geojsonObject = {};
  geojsonObject['type'] = 'FeatureCollection';
  geojsonObject['features'] = [];

  $.each( data.features, function( index, item ) {

    const MvtSpeed = item.properties.MvtSpeed;
    const MvtDirec = item.properties.MvtSpeed;
    
    const startLon = item.properties.LonTrajCellCG[0];
    const startLat = item.properties.LatTrajCellCG[0];
    
    const kmToLon = 1/(111.32 * Math.cos(startLat * (180/Math.PI)));
    let kmToLat   = 1/110.57;
    
    const distKMin15m = (MvtSpeed * 60 * 60)/1000;
    const alpha = (MvtDirec * (180/Math.PI));
    
    const deltaLon = (distKMin15m * Math.cos(alpha) * kmToLon);
    const deltaLat = (distKMin15m * Math.cos(alpha) * kmToLat);
    
    const endLon = parseFloat((startLon + deltaLon).toFixed(4));
    const endLat = parseFloat((startLat + deltaLat).toFixed(4));
    
    var t1 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([(startLon), (startLat)], ukngProj);
    var t2 = ol.proj.fromLonLat([(endLon), (endLat)], ukngProj);
    
    var newFeature = {
      "type": "Feature",
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [t1, t2]
      },
    }
    geojsonObject['features'].push(newFeature);
  });
  return geojsonObject;
}

// load geojson 
var gjson = loadFileAjaxSync(fn, "application/json");

// do the calculations
f = calcTraj1HRSat(JSON.parse(gjson));
```

Now I have access to the coordinates in the expected order.

Comment: Instead of having sync AJAX call, you can also have async call. In this case, instead of returning value with `return xmlhttp.responseText`, just directly process returned data with `calcTraj1HRSat(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText))`.